# ThreeDots (jQuery plugin) truncates everything

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to implement the ThreeDots plugin (http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/) on the project I'm working on.

The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to use it, it truncates the ENTIRE text. For example, the text goes from:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>   In mi eros, adipiscing placerat molestie ut, commodo eget
>   risus. Maecenas lorem risus, vulputate id venenatis nec, 
>   scelerisque vitae urna."

to:

> "..."

when I want something like:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br/>
In mi eros, adipiscing placerat molestie ut, commodo eget..."<br/>
```

I suspect that maybe the image tag contained within the `<div>` tag is causing the problem, but at the same time, the "threedots" attribute of the `<div>` tag becomes the full text of the `span` like it's supposed to, so I'm inclined to think that's not the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling/applying the plugin? Have you looked at the usage guidelines?

Comment: have you considered using CSS `text-overflow:ellipsis;` instead? (okay, it doesn't work in current versions of Firefox, but it will do in a release later this year, and all other browsers have supported it for ages)

Comment: I'm applying the plugin just like they put it up on the web site. But, just in case, I will look at the usage guidelines once again.

Comment: And I can't use text-overflow:ellipsis since it doesn't support trimming my line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text must be inside a span element with a css class 'ellipsis_text' (can be changed). 
Did you set the parameters correctly? Show your code.

Comment: Yes I followed the directions correctly, but it still wouldn't work. In the end I ended up coding up my own plugin :)